# Call from js a class from different current file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The title is quite weird, but I'm going to explain the situation as better as possible.

I have a website with a navbar and each tab is a different php file. For all the files, I've a common js and css file. The directory tree is:

> ```
> -tab1.php
> -tab2.php
> -/js/functions.js
> ```

The problems come when I'm on tab2 and try to get a class from tab1. The class "this_row" is only in tab1 and if I'm in tab2, the values aren't getting. If I draw a div with this class in tab2 all works fine.

```
function showSensorNames(){ 

    $('.this_row').each(function(){
        saveNames.push($(this).find('.btn_view').text());
    });
}
```

And this function is called from `$(document).ready(function(){`

I don't know if there is any way to do it, maybe doing a global function through all the files, or if my way to make a different file for each tab is wrong. I also thought about saving into cookies or session, but I don't think in this as the most appropriate way to do it.

**Update:**
Are there any way where the tabs doesn't be different files? Are there any good tutorial to do this? And then will be recognized

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're navigating away from the current page or not.

If you're loading a whole new page when a user clicks a link, then there is no way to have a persistent global state in JavaScript. You'd need to use a different pageload pattern using AJAX for that.

Depending on what data you're trying to persist between pages, you could use GET, POST, cookies, or even the localStorage API.

Comment: There are two pages, in the same directory (server), called from a navbar. The first file has the class that I'm trying to call from the second file, but both of them share the same js.

Comment: Well even if they share the same JavaScript file, every time you load a new page you're basically wiping the slate clean and running the code from scratch, there is no persistent state.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. As you say there isn't any class `.this_row` on the tab2 page so you can't access it content. If you are trying to get info from the tab1 then may be the tab2 shouldn't be a different tab.

You should explain better what info are you trying to read.

Comment: I'm trying to get the name of some divs in the first tab and then display it again in the second tab. So this cannot be done, isn't? Are there any way to do it, or maybe a way where the different tabs don't be different files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a PHP document for each tab, you are essentially reloading a page (or new page) with each click of a link in your nav. JS dumps any var or objects you created and stored on reload. If you want to be able to pass JS data to the new page - storing the var using HTML5 LocalStorage would be an option.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("color", "blue");
// Retrieve
var retrievable = localStorage.getItem("color");
```

You can also use sessionStorage if you only want the data stored during that session.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid to use a document for each tab? Maybe a good tutorial to follow?

Comment: Look into a  MV* Javascript framework like AngularJS or Ember that are designed for single page web apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use 2 files and you have to share data between, you can use sessionStorage.

When you set

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

When you get

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Note: data will be wiped out when closing the browser.